# Override click in android preferenceactivity

Tags: android, dialog, overriding, preferenceactivity

In my app I'd like to show a warning when using a certain preference in my application. I've tried using the PreferenceActivity.onPreferenceTreeClick and the onPreferenceClickListener, but neither seems to work. I've got the latter example below. Could anyone shed some light on this please?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saved) {

    super.onCreate(saved);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    Preference gridview = findPreference("fcngrid");
    gridview.setOnPreferenceClickListener(overrider);

}

public OnPreferenceClickListener overrider = new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {

        if (pref.getTitle() == "Default as grid")
            showDialog(0);

        return false;
    }

};

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setTitle("Warning")
     .setMessage("Unfortunately, this feature is currently unstable, and will be" +
             " fixed soon.")
     .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.cancel();

        }

     });

    return b.create();

}
```

Comment: Please define "but neither seems to work".

Comment: Sorry, neither way shows the dialog at showDialog(0). It's very odd, I used the debugger and it gets to the if statement; even if I copy and paste the preference title (or key as I'm now using) from a breakpoint it still wont say the statement is true... the debugger shows it should work but it just doesn't. I should point out that if i comment the if statement it works fine, just on every item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, using `pref.getTitle().equals("Default as grid")` worked fine.

Comment: if (pref.getTitle() == "Default as grid")
            showDialog(0); Mhhhh, maybe this one is better:        if (pref== gridview)
            showDialog(0);

Comment: Oh yer, didn't think of that! Probably a much better way of doing it. Thanks!